# Application Pool Identity and 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: windows-7, error, 403

I am trying to understand the cause of this 403 Forbidden Error on my SharePoint Dev machine.

When I installed SP on my Win7 box I added myself as the Application Pool Identity that runs Central Admin. So to fix this I created a new sp_AppPool account on my machine. First attempt to access the site indicated the Farm Config db could not be reached. I then gave SQL Server access with Read/Write/SecurityAdmin rights to the Farm Configuration DB. Then I started getting 403 Forbidden Errors. I gave read/write access to the wss folder in wwwroot - still 403. I then gave read/write to the 14 folder - still 403. I then added sp_AppPool as Admin and it still gives 403.

Looking for reasons so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer (or workaround) for this that you can provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was a loopback problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the app pool manually or did you do it through Central Administration?  I haven't looked at the specifics lately, but there were some local groups on the server that SharePoint creates and puts accounts in for elevated permissions.

Comment: manually but I'll try it through CA to see if that works.

Comment: this does not seem to be the right approach.  CA does not allow local accounts to be selected so I am attempting powershell with no luck so far. :(

Comment: The format should be servername/account.  I've setup a few 2010 labs which were not domain attached and was able to get it to work.  Anything set directly through IIS will be reset with what is in the config database.

Comment: for local accounts you can use ".\username" if the local name of the computer doesnt work.